# Nodejs encryption problems with npm "crypto" module

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptography

When I try to encrypt or decrypt a token, I have this error :

```
internal/crypto/cipher.js:92
    this[kHandle].initiv(cipher, credential, iv, authTagLength);
                  ^

Error: Invalid IV length
```

I have to do the same encryption that's done on this link : [here](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=AES_Encrypt(%7B%27option%27:%27Base64%27,%27string%27:%27xNRxA48aNYd33PXaODSutRNFyCu4cAe/InKT/Rx%2Bbw0%3D%27%7D,%7B%27option%27:%27Base64%27,%27string%27:%2781dFxOpX7BPG1UpZQPcS6w%3D%3D%27%7D,%27CBC%27,%27Raw%27,%27Raw%27)To_Base64(%27A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D%27)Find_/_Replace(%7B%27option%27:%27Regex%27,%27string%27:%27%3D%27%7D,%27%27,true,false,true,false)Find_/_Replace(%7B%27option%27:%27Simple%20string%27,%27string%27:%27%2B%27%7D,%27-%27,true,false,true,false)Find_/_Replace(%7B%27option%27:%27Regex%27,%27string%27:%27/%27%7D,%27_%27,true,false,true,false)&input=cGFydG5lcklkPTEmb3BlcmF0aW9uSWQ9MzAyMTUmY2xpZW50SWQ9Q0RYMTIzNDUmdGltZXN0YW1wPTE1NDU3MzUxODE)

Can someone help me ? :)

Have a great day all !

Here is what i've done:

```
var crypto = require('crypto'),
    key = 'xNRxA48aNYd33PXaODSutRNFyCu4cAe/InKT/Rx+bw0=',
    iv = '81dFxOpX7BPG1UpZQPcS6w==';

function encrypt_token(data) {
    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
    cipher.update(data, 'binary', 'base64');
    return cipher.final('base64');
}

function decrypt_token(data) {
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
    decipher.update(data, 'base64', 'binary');
    return decipher.final('binary');
}

console.log('NodeJS encrypt: ', encrypt_token('partnerId=1&operationId=30215&clientId=CDX12345&timestamp=1545735181'));
console.log('NodeJS decrypt: ', decrypt_token('hxdBZWB4eNn0lstyQU3cIX3WPj4ZLZu-C8qD02QEex8ahvMSMagFJnAGr2C16qMGsOLIcqypO8NX4Tn65DCrXGKrEL5i75tj6WoHGyWAzs0'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use buffer or utf8 strings as parameters for [`createCipheriv`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipheriv_algorithm_key_iv_options)

This works:

```js
'use strict';

const crypto = require('crypto');

const key = Buffer.from('xNRxA48aNYd33PXaODSutRNFyCu4cAe/InKT/Rx+bw0=', 'base64');
const iv = Buffer.from('81dFxOpX7BPG1UpZQPcS6w==', 'base64');

function encrypt_token(data) {
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, iv);
  const encryptedData = cipher.update(data, 'utf8', 'base64') + cipher.final('base64');
  return encryptedData;
}

function decrypt_token(data) {
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
  const decripted = decipher.update(data, 'base64', 'utf8') + decipher.final('utf8');
  return decripted;
}

console.log('NodeJS encrypt: ', encrypt_token('partnerId=1&operationId=30215&clientId=CDX12345&timestamp=1545735181'));
console.log('NodeJS decrypt: ', decrypt_token('hxdBZWB4eNn0lstyQU3cIX3WPj4ZLZu-C8qD02QEex8ahvMSMagFJnAGr2C16qMGsOLIcqypO8NX4Tn65DCrXGKrEL5i75tj6WoHGyWAzs0'));
```

Note also that you need to concat the results of `update` and `final`